# QGIS - Symbology changing with the scale

Tags: qgis, symbology, scale

I am wondering if it is possible to change the symbology of a map when zooming in and zooming out. For example, at a 1:500000 scale I have this rendering

[image]

And when I zoom at a 1:5000 scale, they split and appear like so

[image]

How can I achieved this type of rendering with QGIS ?

Comment: What kind of data do you have? Vector or raster?

Comment: @BERA points as vector

Answer (score 4):

You can set the scale in `rule based` symbology

[image]

Comment: To add onto this, if you want to use complex scale rules (e.g. one scale range for the main canvas, another for the main map in print layout, yet another for a different map in print layout), you can also use the @map_scale variable when defining the symbol rule.